# What kind of logical operator is?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm a newbie with mathematica ,I came across this sign, could someone tell me what that means?
=!=

```
If[m - l =!= 0, net0 = convtomat[dd,m - l];
    row0 = {}; row1 = {}; row2 = {};
    Do[
      row1 = Append[row1, net0[[1, j + 1]]], {j, 0, m - l}
      ];
    ccts = Join[ccts, row1],
    ccts = Join[ccts, dd]
  ]
```

Comment: You can always position your cursor at the right end of something, give it a left mouse click, tap the F1 function key and it should take you to the documentation page for that. That should help you many many times in the near future. If you want more information you can always click on the little triangle next to the "Details and Options" or sometimes it is just "Details" and that will provide some more in-depth information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [`UnsameQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnsameQ.html) operator.

`m - l =!= 0`, will return true if `m - l` is not identical to `0`. Otherwise, it will return false.